# Printing strings + input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, output

I'm trying to find a way to format my input, reserving some space after it and then printing some characters all in the same line.

This code obviously doesn't work, but may bright to you my needs:

```
print('|') + var=input("What's your name: ")+(reserved 10 characters) +print('|')
```

or:

```
char + input command + Reserverd space + char
```

I need this result:

`'|What's your name?>>>                           |'`

First '|' is ok, but the second? and the space?

Thank  you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do directly. There are two ways around it.

---

First, you can print terminal control sequences directly, to print out this:

```
| What's your name:          |
```

… and then move the cursor after the colon for the user's input. Fortunately, you're just dealing with a single line here, so all you need is backspace, which is `'\x08'` on almost all terminals you're going to run into, so it's just:

```
var = input("| What's your name:          |\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08")
```

However, the user will be able to type over the second `|`, and on some terminals the `|` will be erased as soon as he his enter, and on some terminals it may even be erased just by backspacing over it.

You can get more sophisticated by using a `termcap` library, and maybe by using `readline`, but there are always going to be limitations here; the terminal is in line-buffered mode, so your code can't have any control over what happens until the user hits enter.

---

Alternatively, you can take over the terminal and manage user input manually, to keep the user within 10 characters. On *nix platforms, this is a complicated mess of `tcsetattr` and `select`ing and `read`ing from `stdin`; on Windows, it's a bunch of "conio" calls in `mscvrt` that are simpler, but less well documented.

However, if you really want to do this, you should probably be using a higher-level library, like `curses`.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but in idle the backspace \x08  is putting the cursor in front of my last character and it isn't coming backwards. I'll try tomorrow in  my work over Windows terminal and see how it will react because my code  will run only in Windows. Thank you very much!  If it works I'll answer you in here.

Comment: @user3927115: There's no way to make this work in IDLE, because it doesn't use a terminal, and fakes `input` in the GUI. If you care about how it looks in IDLE, you will have to write Tkinter code to replace the command-line code, and detect that you're in IDLE. But you really shouldn't care about how it looks in IDLE; that's a developer tool, that your users will not be using to run your code.